# UITable DidSelectRowAtIndexPath not sending data over via segue (Unexpectedly found nil)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, segue

I'm trying to send data from one table in viewController A to viewController B. However whenever I try to I keep get the error message `Unexpectedly found nil`.

I have all of my data in a data class array which is being called and written into the table cells, I then have a segue which should pass across the `selectedCell` data across to a var in the 2nd viewController called `cellData`

```
if segue.identifier == "viewMemorySegue" {
            let viewMemoryVC = segue.destinationViewController as! memoryViewierViewController
            viewMemoryVC.cellData = selectedCell!
        }
```

I then have a `didSelectRow` function which is setting the `selectedCell` data and then `performing segue`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedCell = cacheData[indexPath.row]
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("viewMemorySegue", sender: self)
}
```

I have tired `print(cellData.memoryTitle)` within the `didSelect` function to see if it was nil, however it was printing out the correct data.

Im new to Xcode and swift so all help is appreciated!!!

**GITHub Project Link**
https://github.com/Matthammond96/Relive

Comment: why tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true) should be -> tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

Comment: @khuong291 cheers, will change that however it hasn't fixed the nil issue :(

Comment: You must hold the selected cell data in a private property which should be strong and then use that for passing the data.

Comment: `deselct` would not be causing that. Put some breakpoints on destination VC of `viewMemorySegue` and see if your code reaches `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidLoad` of that VC. That should narrow down which VC is causing the nil exception

Comment: git hub project does not contain any tables, please push your latest changes. does the error show any line numbers or filenames where the error occurred? Might not be where you expect

Comment: @Scriptable I'm having trouble pushing 1 min

Comment: @Scriptable pushed the latest version sorry about that

Comment: ok, looking at it now

Comment: @Scriptable Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a selection segue set in your storyboard which is set to open the `MemoryViewerViewController` and I don't see a delegate set in the `FindCacheViewController` so your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function is not being called, therefore... your `selectedCell` property is not being set.

[image]

I would remove the storyboard segue that you have, set your delegate up properly and then it should work.

I added a print output in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and it was never called.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("TEST")
        selectedCell = cacheData[indexPath.row]
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        //performSegueWithIdentifier("viewMemorySegue", sender: self)
   }
```

As you will notice, I also commented out the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method call and the segue still tried to happen from the storyboard segue you have.

Comment: If I remove the data sending part from the segue, it will perform the segue,

Comment: Yes, that's because of the storyboard segue you have setup. Basically you have two methods of activating the segue at the moment. Only one of them sets the data but it is never called.

Comment: Ok, also should that be DeSelect or Select?, Select right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. In the screenshot you see Triggered Segues. Remove that completely. in your FindCacheViewController you should have an outlet for your table view. Then in viewDidLoad set the delegate like `tableView.delegate = self` then the didSelectRowAtIndexPath should be called. Then fire the segue from there after data is set. Ah you do have an outlet already, locationTableView. use that and set the delegate

Comment: I think in his VC B, there is no data, so it can't show anything.

Comment: I've just about got it working on my machine now, give me a few mins

Comment: That fixed it :) So the segue being attached to the cell must have been overwriting the didSelectFunction. Thanks dude

Comment: Thats a mistake I shall never make again it took way to long @Scriptable & khuong thank you both for helping

Answer (score 1):

If your data is global, you don't have to declare it in VC B, if it is local in side VC A, then you have to declare it in VC B. Then in your VC B, create the `var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?`. Then in your VC A, create `var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?`. Then in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function, send the selected index path to `selectedIndexPath` like this `tableView.indexPathForCell(cellFromDelegateMethod)`

And then

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "viewMemorySegue" {            
        let viewMemoryVC = segue.destinationViewController as! memoryViewierViewController
        viewMemoryVC.selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath!
    }
  }
```

Comment: He is using a TableView not a collectionView.

Comment: quick question how does that write to the cellData var in the other VC?

Comment: Well Matt proper way for transmission of data is through `prepareForSegue`. You just have to create an appropriate property in the destination VC and assign your desired data to that property.

Comment: the VC2 should have a variable callen selectedIndexPath, then when prepareForSegue, just send the selectedCell at VC1 to this VC2, viewMemoryVC.selectedIndexPath = selctedCell

Comment: I make sure it will right, because I've done this before. NSNoob, please remove the downvote.

Comment: @khuong291 It's not mine :)

Comment: That was my downvote. Because the code is incorrect. I'll remove it once its fixed

Comment: Will fix it soon, please wait a minute

Comment: @khuong291 sorry not sure what you mean?

Comment: It mean, in your VC B, make sure it will acess the data, if not, it has nothing to show even the selected cell has send to it. Got it?

Comment: Cheers for the help but the data is now being written to the segued var from the code that I had but Thank you anyway as I said I'm new to swift and all help is needed and appreciated :) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

First View Controller which is with the table view:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    private var cellData: String!
    //MARK - TableViewDatasource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "data \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        self.cellData = cell.textLabel?.text
        performSegueWithIdentifier("AnotherViewControllerSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            let destinationVC : AnotherViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnotherViewController
            destinationVC.data = self.cellData;
        }
    }
```

Next, Another View Controller with property to hold the data

```
class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {
    var data:NSString!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            NSLog(self.data as String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference between this and what I have, what are the benefits etc?

Comment: I checked out his code and did not find any code what so ever about UITableView so I prepared my answer based on some assumptions. While this method will also work, the accepted answer is also correct. If one is using static cell, he can directly make segue to another view controller from that cell but if one is using dynamic cell, he will need to perhaps create generic segue and use performSegueWithIdentifier method.